# Question about property of 2-increasing, grounded function with margins

Tags: joint-distribution, copula, inequality

The question is about what may very well be an obvious detail in the proof of a lemma from the book An Introduction to Copulas by Roger Nelsen. I will state all the relevant results and definitions below. My question is about a detail in the proof of lemma 2.1.5. Please excuse the lengthy post.

**Definition (Several in one)**
A 2-place real function $H$ is a function whose domain, Dom$H$, is a subset of the Cartesian product of the extended real numbers, and whose range, Ran$H$, is a subset of the real numbers.

Let $S_{1}$ and $S_{2}$ be nonempty subsets of the extended real numbers, and let $H$ be a two-place real function such that Dom$H = S_{1}\times S_{2}$. Let $B = [x_{1}, x_{2}]\times [y_{1}, y_{2}]$ be a rectangle all of whose vertices are in Dom$H$. Then the *H-volume of B* is given by $$V_{H}(B) = H(x_{2},y_{2})-H(x_{2},y_{1})-H(x_{1},y_{2})+H(x_{1},y_{1})$$.

A 2-place real function is *2-increasing* if $V_{H}(B)\geq 0$ for all rectangles $B$ whose vertices lie in Dom$H$.

**Lemma 2.1.3**
Let $S_{1}$ and $S_{2}$ be nonempty subsets of the extended real numbers and let $H$ be a 2-increasing function with domain $S_{1}\times S_{2}$. Let $x_{1}, x_{2}$ be in $S_{1}$ with $x_{1}\leq x_{2}$, and let $y_{1}, y_{2}$ be in $S_{2}$ with $y_{1}\leq y_{2}$. Then the function $t \mapsto H(t,y_{2}) - H(t,y_{1})$ is nondecreasing on $S_{1}$, and the function $t \mapsto H(x_{2},t) - H(x_{1},t)$ is nondecreasing on $S_{2}$.

**Definition**
Suppose $S_{1}$ has a least element $a_{1}$ and that $S_{2}$ has a least element $a_{2}$. We say that a function $H$ from $S_{1}\times S_{2}$ into the real numbers is *grounded* if $H(x,a_{2}) = 0 = H(a_{1},y)$ for all $(x,y)$ in $S_{1}\times S_{2}$.

**Lemma 2.1.4**
Let $S_{1}$ and $S_{2}$ be nonempty subsets of the extended real numbers, and let $H$ be a grounded 2-increasing function with domain $S_{1}\times S_{2}$. Then $H$ is non-decreasing in each argument.

**Definition**
Suppose $S_{1}$ has a greatest element $b_{1}$ and that $S_{2}$ has a greatest element $b_{2}$. We say that a function $H$ from $S_{1}\times S_{2}$ into the real numbers *has margins*, and that the margins of $H$ are the functions $F$ and $G$ given by:

Dom$F$ = $S_{1}$, and $F(x) = H(x,b_{2})$ for all $x \in S_{1}$;
Dom$G$ = $S_{2}$ and $G(y) = H(b_{1},y)$ for all $y\in S_{2}$.

**Lemma 2.1.5**
Let $S_{1}$ and $S_{2}$ be nonempty subsets of the extended real numbers, and let $H$ be a grounded 2-increasing function, with margins, whose domain is $S_{1}\times S_{2}$. Let $(x_{1}, y_{1})$ and $(x_{2}, y_{2})$ be any points in $S_{1}\times S_{2}$. Then

$|H(x_{2},y_{2})-H(x_{1},y_{1})|\leq |F(x_{2}-F(x_{1})| + |G(y_{2})-G(y_{1})|$.

My questions concerns a detail in the following proof.

*Proof*. From the triangle inequality, we have
$|H(x_{2},y_{2})-H(x_{1},y_{1})|\leq |H(x_{2},y_{2})-H(x_{1},y_{2})| + |H(x_{1},y_{2})-H(x_{1},y_{1})|$.

Now assume $x_{1}\leq x_{2}$. Because $H$ is grounded, 2-increasing, and has margins, lemmas 2.1.3 and 2.1.4 yield $0\leq H(x_{2},y_{2})-H(x_{1},y_{2})\leq F(x_{2})-F(x_{1})$...

This last inequality is what caused my confusion. As I understand it, $F(x_{2})\geq H(x_{2},y_{2})$, but we also have $F(x_{1})\geq H(x_{1},y_{2})$, i.e. $-F(x_{1})\leq -H(x_{1},y_{2})$ , so that we cannot simply add/subtract the left hand sides and right hand sides of the inequalities. If my understanding is correct, the inequality in question must be estimated differently, but so far I have not been successful in doing so. This has been bugging me for a while because this seems like it should be so simple, given that one has understood the relevant definitions and prior results. Therefore, this causes me to believe that I may have misunderstood some part of the relevant information I provided. Any help would therefore be much appreciated. Thanks in advance to all that take the time to read this rather long entry.

Answer (score 0):

I think the following answers the question: Rewriting the condition for being 2-increasing, we get that $H(x_{2},y_{2})-H(x_{1},y_{2}) \geq H(x_{2},y_{1})-H(x_{1},y_{1})$, which holds for any $x_{2}\geq x_{1}$ and $y_{2}\geq y_{1}$. In particular, since $H$ has margins, we know there exists a greatest element in $S_{2}$, denoted $y^{*}$. By the definition of margins, we get $F(x_{2}) = H(x_{2},y^{*})$ and $F(x_{1}) = H(x_{1},y^{*})$. By the rewritten condition for $H$ being 2-increasing, this implies that $F(x_{2})-F(x_{1})\geq H(x_{2},y_{2})-H(x_{1},y_{2})$.